# grep in CSV file

Tags: linux, grep

probably there is a lot already written about this, but I´m struggling to catch how the structure works in grep in order to launch a query on to a csv file.

the file I´m working on has the following structure:

```
Field1, field2, field3, field4, field5
numeric, leter, numeric, characters, characters
```

```
12,F,27,finnish,english swedish french spanish
16,F,29,finnish,english swedish french spanish estonian 
30,F,19,finnish,english swedish french spanish
```

Basically what I´m struggling with is defining a specific condition of for each field within the CSV

Below, the expression I've come up y with

```
grep -E "[1-9][[:digit:]][^,]\,F[^,]\,[23][^,]\,finnish[^,]\, spanish.*french |  french.*spanish
```

And here the search that I need to implement in grep

```
first field --> numers above 10
scond field --> letter that matches F
third field --> numbers within a range
forth field --> chain of characters
fifth field --> chain of characters
```

my patience is getting to the limit... :)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

```sh
first field --> numers above 10
scond field --> letter that matches F
third field --> numbers within a range
forth field --> chain of characters
fifth field --> chain of characters
```

`awk` is much more suitable for this job as you can split record on comma and then check individual fields for all the conditions:

```sh
awk -F, '
   $1 > 10 && $2 == "F" && $3 >= 20 && $3 <= 30
   && $4 ~ /^finnish/ && $5 ~ /spanish.*french|french.*spanish/
' file

12,F,27,finnish,english swedish french spanish
16,F,29,finnish,english swedish french spanish estonian
```

Comment: Yep I know, but the thing is that need to use grep! Thanks in any case

Comment: Unless it is an academic exercise grep is not the right tool for this problem